# converting an uploaded csv to python list

Tags: python, list, cgi

I have a two-column csv which I have uploaded via an HTML page to be operated on by a python cgi script.  Looking at the file on the server side, it looks to be a long string i.e for a file called test.csv with the contents.

```
col1,  col2  
x,y
```

has become

```
('upfile', 'test.csv', 'col1,col2'\t\r\nx,y')
```

Col1 contains the data I want to operate on (i.e. x) and col 2 contains its identifier (y).  Is there a better way of doing the uploading or do I need to manually extract the fields I want - this seems potentially very error-prone 
thanks

Comment: `('upfile', 'test.csv', 'col1,col2'\t\r\nx,y')` has unbalanced single-quote (`'`) characters. Please don't type from memory; copy/paste. Please edit your question to show *exactly* what you have got ... the `\t` is also suspicious.

Comment: @John Yes, sorry.  There is no quote after col2.  The \t is there though

Comment: Are you sure that the tab (`\t`) is AFTER col2? In what you say that your input looks like (`col1,  col2`) I'd be betting the tab is BEFORE cols.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the `cgi` module in python, you should be able to do something like:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
thefile = form['upfile']

reader = csv.reader(thefile.file)
header = reader.next() # list of column names
for row in reader:
    # row is a list of fields
    process_row(row)
```

See, for example, [cgi programming](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm) or the python [cgi module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) docs.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use the csv module to parse this? It certantly better than rolling your own.

Something along the lines of

```
import csv
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
thefile = form['upfile']

reader = csv.reader(thefile, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
  for field in row:
    doThing()
```

**EDIT**: Correcting my answer from the ars answer posted below.

Comment: The csv module has always been more trouble than it's worth for me. Can you explain the advantage of the above vs `rows = [row.split(',') for r in csv_string.split('\r\n')]`? I'm not trying to be antagonistic. I seriously don't know.

Comment: @dustynachos Your solution doesn't work if one of the fields has a , on it, for example. The csv module does proper quoting of fields and such.

Comment: Ah... Now that you mention it I did run into this once. My solution was another regular expression which, as the saying goes, was not so much a solution as another problem.

Comment: @dustynachos As the jwz quote says: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems. :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers.  I'll try out the ones based on the csv module.  I really would like to avoid the "manual" regex route.  I'm using the html upload approach as the end users of the page won't know about ftp, and I don't know about ways to use ftp in an html page.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your file is becoming modified by the HTML upload.  Is there anything stopping you from just ftp'ing in and dropping the csv file where you need it?

Once the CSV file is more proper, here is a quick function that will put it into a 2D array:

```
def genTableFrCsv(incsv):
    table = []
    fin = open(incsv, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    for row in reader: 
        table.append(row)
    fin.close()
    return table
```

From here you can then operate on the whole list in memory rather than pulling bit by bit from the file as in Vitor's solution.

Answer (score -2):

The easy solution is `rows = [row.split('\t') for r in csv_string.split('\r\n')]`. It's only error proned if you have users from different platforms submit data. They might submit comas or tabs and their line breaks could be \n, \r\n, \r, or ^M. The easiest solution is to use regular expressions. Book mark this page if you don't know regular expressions:

http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

And here's the solution:

```
import re

csv_string = 'col1,col2'\t\r\nx,y' #obviously your csv opening code goes here

rows = re.findall(r'(.*?)[\t,](.*?)',csv_string)
rows = rows[1:] # remove header
```

Rows is now a list of tuples for all of the rows.

Comment: The easiest solution is the csv module, not regular expressions :)

Comment: -1 (1) Don't use regexes to attempt to parse csv, html, xml, etc etc (2) Didn't you notice that the `csv_string = ...` line has a syntax error when you ran it?? (3) `^M` aka `Ctrl-M` is the same as `\r` (4) Doesn't `col1,col2` suggest to you that the OP wants to split on commas? (5) You think that all input varieties can be correctly handled by treating `\t` and comma identically???